# How to remove words which ends with this words?

Tags: java, string

I want to remove words which ends with these strings

```
hello_hi
sorry_hr
good_tt
```

I want to remove words which ends with `_tt`,`_hr`. how to do it?

```
     is this is good way?

       String word = word.replace("_hi", "");
```

Comment: Do you want to keep the word and remove the token `_hi` and `_hr`?

Comment: Do you want to remove the words of somewhere? or actually what you want is removing the ends of the words?

Comment: I want to remove the whole word which ends like that. Also I want to remove the token which I want to keep.

Comment: Remove the word from where exactly? You want to `remove the token which you want to keep`? What this means exactly?

Comment: thats means if the word ends with _hi,_tt i must remove the entire word ie remove hello_hi.

If it ends with _hr. I must remove _hr from the word and keep the sorry.

Comment: Remove from where? where  are exactly the words store to be removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have a single String like:

```
     String str = "hello_hi sorry_hr good_tt";
```

Then what you want is summarized in these three rules to be applied:

1) Remove hello_hi because it ends with _hi

2) Remove _hr and keep the word behind, for this particular case it will keep sorry

3) Keep good_tt, because it has not *_hi or *_hr form, but *_tt

Then, the final string will be "sorry good_tt"

Let's do that

```
    String[] strings = str.split(" ");
    ArrayList processed = new ArrayList();
    for (String token : strings) {
        if (token.endsWith("_hr")){ //rule 2
            processed.add(token.replace("_hr", ""));
        } else if (token.endsWith("_hi")) { //rule 1
            continue;
        } else { //any other case, rule 3
            processed.add(token); 
        }
    }
```

That way, you will have in processed List the results: **"sorry"** and **"good_tt"**

```
    System.out.println(processed.toString());
```

Getting the following output:

```
    [sorry, good_tt]
```

Comment: no use. still it prints the same

Comment: what do you mean? can you clarify please? I have done my best to understand your question and preparing a step-by-step answer, please feel free to edit it on any part  that is not correct. The answer is the community wiki kind, so you can edit it!!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a String which contains the your token which ends with for e.g. `_tt` and you want to remove that word from that String.

```
String[] tokens = yourStr.split(" ");
for (String t : tokens) {
   if (t.endsWith("_tt") {
       yourStr = yourStr.replaceAll(t, "");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html)?

Comment: I thought to use regular expressions. But Still confused with how to use the regex that accurate

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] tokens = str.split(" ");
List<String> good = Lists.newArrayList();
for (String token : tokens) {
    if (token.endsWith("_hr") || token.endsWith("_tt")) continue;
    good.add(clip_end(token));
}
join(good);
```

`String clip_end(String str)` should clip the _hi off.  It's just a simple call to indexOf and then substring.

`String join(List<String> strs)` just concatenates with spaces.

In the spirit of SO, you get to write clip and join.  FOr extra credit, replace the `good` list with a StringBuilder and write your output directly into it.